# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 with EncryptedCoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cocoapods

I use EncryptedCoreData to encrypt CoreData. Integrate it with pod ( pod 'EncryptedCoreData', :git => 'https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data.git'), in Bridging-Header - file I include:

```
#import <EncryptedCoreData/EncryptedStore.h>
```

, but I have such error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EncryptedStore", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo14EncryptedStore in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you added the library to your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pods Xcode project -> build setting, set build for active architecture only to 'NO'

Comment: I set "NO", but it doesn't help me.